# Tool to detect C++ template issues

Tags: c++, templates, g++, static-analysis

I recently spent some time hunting down a typo in my C++ templates. g++ did not complain about the typo, so I was wondering if there is a tool which can check for this type of problem in the future?

Here is a simplified example which demonstrates the correct compilation. I would expect a complaint about struct dummy not being defined, but it seems like the templated class goo hides that.

foo.h:

```
struct smart {
    int x, y, z;
};

template<typename T> class goo
{
    void barf(T* ptr){}
};

template<typename T> class foo 
{
public:
    foo(){};
private:
    goo<T> x;
};

class bar: public foo<struct dummy>
{
public:
    void do_something(struct smart& thing){}
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    bar a;
    struct smart b;
    a.do_something(b);
    return b.x+b.y+b.z;
}
```

Compiles successfully with g++ foo.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **compiler**, set at the highest warning levels, is the best tool you have for detecting any C++ issue.

My advice to you is two fold:

1) Set your compiler warning levels at the highest level.  This will catch many mistakes that lower levels may remain silent on.

2) Use a coding style that is more apt to generate compiler errors when you do something wrong.  For example:

```
class bar: public foo<struct dummy>
{
public:
    void do_something(struct smart& thing){}
};
```

I honestly don't know if this code is legal or not.  I strongly suspect not, but it does appear that you're declaring a new type `struct dummy`.  The compiler accepts it, and so I'm not sure if it's legit.

You would have been well-served by doing this instead:

```
class bar: public foo<dummy>
{
public:
    void do_something(struct smart& thing){}
};
```

Now this can never be parsed as a new type declaration, and the compiler will refuse it.  This would have caught your problem early.

Comment: I used -Wall, -Wextra, and -pedantic and the compiler still did not catch the error. Any suggestions for additional/alternative [options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) to use?

Comment: The code may be legit as written.  If so, no tool will ever find the problem for you because there is no problem -- that's my point.  Don't use `<struct dummy>` -- use `<dummy>` instead.

Comment: If you're looking for more compiler help, use more compilers. Depending on your platform, you should have at least one of clang, icc, or msvc available, and they'll all give different errors and warnings. You can also find various online compilers. Unfortunately, none of that would help in your case, because the code actually is legitimate—but in general, you'll find a lot more useful warnings with g++ and clang than with g++ with two different sets of options.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using the template type parameters (which is the case in your example) the code is OK, even if the type does not exist or you are calling a function on the type in a member function that is not being called.  This is in the name of C++'s if you don't use it you don't pay for it (e.g no new function is created).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use `struct dummy` the compiler is told to auto generate a forward declaration struct if there is no such struct exiting. If you use just `dummy` without `struct` it will not do so and it will complain.

Answer (score 0):

[Attilla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606339/11698) has nailed this; the definition of `dummy` is not needed 
and so it can remain as an incomplete type.  This is an extremely useful
feature of C/C++ as it helps with information hiding and also with
reducing compile times.

For example:

```
// Afwd.h
class A;
A * getA ();
void processA(A *);
void printA (A *);


// t.cc
#include "Afwd.h"
void bar ()
{
  A * a = getA ();
  processA (a);
  printA (a);
}
```

Here, it's unnecessary for clients of `A` to see its implementation details.  This also has the advantage that clients do not need to include headers that are required for the definition of `A`

In order to generate an error against `dummy` in the original example, the definition must be used in this translation unit.

Firstly, `ptr` needs to be used in a way which requires a complete type, for example via a dereference:

```
template<typename T> class goo
{
public:
    void barf(T* ptr){
      *ptr;           
    }
};
```

This still isn't a problem as the function `barf` is not called and so is not instantiated:

```
template<typename T> class foo 
{
public:
    foo(){
      x.barf (0);
    };
private:
    goo<T> x;
};
```

This code now generates an error.  The constructor of `bar` instantiates and calls the definition of `foo` which instantiates and calls `barf`.